# Queries in IFD environment

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-4, crm

We are migrating our applications from on-premise to IFD.  We have some webpages that creates some kind of queries to the CRM Views (ie `Select * from account`). These queries work well in on-premise environment but when we run on IFD environment we have this exeception

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

How can we do this in IFD, being sure that the query returns only the rows the user has permission?

Answer (score 0):

when moving over from on premise you have to start "impersonating" users as you are not working on active directory anymore...

first of all you should NEVER be using the account table, you should be using the filteredaccount views as this is the supported way.

Comment: Hi John, I am doing a similar thing whereby our website is hosted on Azure as a cloud service and I am trying to make calls to our AD authenticated CRM account also hosted on azure but I am unsure as to what authentication type to be using, I have tried AD but this is not working via the WSDL queries, I am however able to open the CRM server from a web browser on the Website server so I know that this is not a firewall issue, how can I add impersonation so that I am essentially passing in the values from the web.config file to authenticate via AD